# It was not an option/It was not in the options

Tags: word-usage

The online ink blot tests aren't really efficient becuse they have a fixed number of options to choose from.  Someone took a test. One of the ink blots looked like a "dress" to a person,  but it was not something that they had included in their opinions (4 options).

The person can say:

> It looked like a dress to me, but it wasn't included in the options.
>
> It looked like a dress to me, but it wasn't in the options.
>
> It looked like a dress to me, but it wasn't part of options.
>
> It looked like a dress to me, but it wasn't an option.

Which out of these four sounds the most natural to you and is likely to be used?

Comment: *It looked like a dress to me, but that wasn't one of the options.*

Answer (score -2):

In this context, you should say "it wasn't included *among* the options" (not "in"). This is because you are counting one option (the dress) among the other options, so you are speaking about "options" in the plural. As an example, take a class of schoolchildren. You might say "Johnny is *in* the class" but you would say "Johnny is *among* the children", not "in". This is because while "class" is the collective noun, "children" is the plural.

Note that the noun "options" can also be used as a *collective noun*. For example, you might say "I went *in* the options on my smartphone". Here you are using "options" not as something countable, but to describe one page in your phone's UI where all the options are collected. It is this kind of context where "in" is acceptable.

So, of your suggestions, the one I feel is correct is:

> It looked like a dress to me but it wasn't an option.

You could also say:

> It looked like a dress to me but it wasn't *among* the options.
>   It looked like a dress to me but it wasn't *one of* the options.

Comment: Are you happy with the abrupt change of referent for 'it'? And have you evidence that 'included in' is incorrect (technically or ... er ...)? [[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=included+in+the+options%2Cincluded+among+the+options&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cincluded%20in%20the%20options%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cincluded%20among%20the%20options%3B%2Cc0)] don't seem to agree.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your sarcastic tone doesn't really help. It would depend on the context.

Comment: Would you prefer an unexplained downvote (as per the anonymous downvoter)?  (a) I see you've removed the sentences where the referent for 'it' abruptly changes. (b) [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=included+in+the+options%2Cincluded+among+the+options&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cincluded%20in%20the%20options%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cincluded%20among%20the%20options%3B%2Cc0) show that "included among the options" does not appear as often as " "included in the options" (though the latter will probably show more ...

Comment: false positives, such as _included in the options package_).  "I feel you should say" is indicative of opinion, not the properly supported answer advocated in the Help Center. Opinion is for _comments_, if anywhere. (c) One spends too much time pointing out that 'technically' is shorthand for something like "I seem to remember some teacher / book / old prescriptive rule that claimed ...", where no research is shown. // Is it better expressed baldly?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Actually what your ngram shows is that "among the options" was used far more for *most* of the 1930s - 1980s, and then an exponential rise of "in the options" from that time onwards. The 1980s saw the dawn of personal computing, and I mention in my answer that "in the options" is perhaps appropriate when using "options" as a collective noun rather than a plural, which computer applications often do.

Comment: And now you've dropped the *it* from your suggestions, turning a perfectly grammatical, although slightly confusing, sentence to a non-grammatical one. You shouldn't listen to other people's bad suggestions as much as you do.

Comment: @Peter The obvious solution is to use 'that'.

Comment: So is "it wasn't in the options" natural or not?  I'm confused.....